# IPython not available in PyDev console

Tags: eclipse, pydev, ipython, qgis

I would like to use the IPython interpreter in Eclipse/PyDev. 
PyDev however does not recognize my IPython installation.

The results I get is the following:

```
>>> import sys; print('%s %s' % (sys.executable or sys.platform, sys.version))
PyDev console: using default backend (IPython not available).
D:\QuantumGIS\apps\Python25\python.exe 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Feb 21 2008, 13:11:45) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)]
>>> import IPython
>>>
```

The "import IPython" command does work.
I'm using

- Windows XP 32 bit
- Eclipse 3.7.2
- PyDev 2.4.0
- IPython 0.10.2
- Python 2.5 (version that is supplied with QGIS 1.7.3)

How should I set up PyDev so I can use IPython as the interactive interpreter?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's the same issue but from Fabio's blog he said to try in the python console (import IPython worked ok):

```
from IPython.frontend.terminal.interactiveshell import TerminalInteractiveShell
```

which gave me nothing useful and:

```
from IPython.frontend.prefilterfrontend import PrefilterFrontEnd
```

Which complained that twisted wasn't installed.  I installed twisted 12.0 for Python 2.5 and it's dependency Zope (3.8 for Python 2.5), restarted the IDE and the console now shows ipython.  There was something about ipython actually using XMLRPC to communicate with the IDE so I guess twisted is needed for that.

Hope that helps.

Stu.

- Windows 7
- Aptana studio 3.1.2 (version of eclipse)
- PyDev 2.5.0 IPython 0.10
- Python 2.5 (needed for some old code I'm working on and haven't
  upgraded yet)